# How to configure apache to accept IP address

Tags: macos, apache

I recently forwarded a dns to my ip address. When I enter my ip into the browser, it says, "The connection was reset". I don't understand what the problem is. When I ping the site name, my ip is shown.

Comment: I registered a domain and linked it to my ip. Like typing 'google.com' would do the same thing as typing '173.194.115.70'. No, site does not show with host, but with localhost

Comment: What exactly does this mean?  "When I ping the site name, my ip is shown."  How did you accomplish this exactly?  DNS changes take a while to propagate. You might just need to wait.

Comment: @AllInOne I opened Terminal and typed 'ping krii.tk' and packages were transmitted to my local IP. It's been about a month and it still says the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is relatively simple. Configure your router to accept port 80/443.
[portforward.com](http://portforward.com/store/pfconfig.cgi) should help.